# how to match log file with date syntax

Tags: grep, logs, date

we have logs like this

```
more log

20/08/02 13:41:39 some text 
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB
20/08/02 13:41:40 some text 
20/08/02 13:41:41 some text 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347
20/08/02 13:41:42 some text 
20/08/02 13:41:43 some text 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347
```

I want to match only the lines with date

so we do that

```
echo "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")"
```

it gives us

```
2020/08/02
```

***but when we try to grep the date to log we not get any output***

example:

```
 grep  "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")" log
```

what is wrong with my grep syntax

?

expected output

```
20/08/02 13:41:39 some text 
20/08/02 13:41:40 some text 
20/08/02 13:41:41 some text 
20/08/02 13:41:42 some text 
20/08/02 13:41:43 some text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines you're looking for start with `20/08/02`, not with `2020/08/02`. Try `%y` instead of `%Y`, this will give the [last two digits of the year](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html).